# Loop with diamond (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to make the loop from the west corner of diamond to the east corner of diamond is like the figure ?

**Figure**

[image]

**Code**

```
       \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
       \usepackage{tikz}
       \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
       \usepackage{amssymb}
       \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth, auto, semithick,
                 node distance=3cm,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,
                 mynode/.style={fill=white,draw,
                 diamond,thick,inner sep=5pt}]
        \node[mynode] (A) {$1$};
        \node[mynode] (B)[right of=A]  {$2$};
        \node[mynode] (C)[right of=B]  {$3$};
        \node[mynode] (D)[right of=C]  {$4$};

        \path[black](A.east) edge[bend left] node{S} (B.west)
                    (B.west) edge[bend left] node{U} (A.east)
                    (B.east) edge node{E} (C.west) 
                    (C.east) edge node{S} (D.west)
                    (B) edge[loop above] node{P} (B)
                    (B) edge[loop below] node{C} (B)
                    (C) edge[loop above] node{N} (C);
       \end{tikzpicture}
       \end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method, using three separate `\draw`s.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth, auto, semithick,
          node distance=3cm,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,
          mynode/.style={fill=white,draw,
          diamond,thick,inner sep=5pt}]
 \node[mynode] (A) {$1$};
 \node[mynode] (B)[right of=A]  {$2$};
 \node[mynode] (C)[right of=B]  {$3$};
 \node[mynode] (D)[right of=C]  {$4$};

 \path[black](A.east) edge[bend left] node{S} (B.west)
             (B.west) edge[bend left] node{U} (A.east)
             (B.east) edge node{E} (C.west) 
             (C.east) edge node{S} (D.west);
 \draw       (B.west) to[out=110,in=70,looseness=3] node{P} (B.east);
 \draw       (B.west) to[out=-110,in=-70,looseness=3] node[swap]{C} (B.east);
 \draw       (C.west) to[out=110,in=70,looseness=3] node{N} (C.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you clarify the role of `looseness=3`?

Comment: @Fabrice just try changing the value, and you'll see. Basically it defines how wide the loop will bw.

Comment: Sorry for this request, I had actually tested different values to understand.

Comment: @Fabrice Oh, no worries. For more information about specific keys like that, the [TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) is usually helpful, by the way. Search for `looseness`, and you'll find it fairly quickly. (A useful tip in that regard: commands and keys in code examples and text are usually hyperlinks leading to where they're described, so if your first hit during searching the PDF is code, then you can typically click `looseness` to jump to its description.)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with using libraries `arrows.meta`, `bending` and `quotes` and `arc` instead of `loop`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, quotes, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[-{Stealth[bend]}, auto, semithick,
     node distance=3cm,
     shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,
     mynode/.style={diamond,draw, thick, minimum size=8mm, inner sep=0pt}
                       ]
\node[mynode] (A) {$1$};
\node[mynode] (B)[right of=A]  {$2$};
\node[mynode] (C)[right of=B]  {$3$};
\node[mynode] (D)[right of=C]  {$4$};

\path[black](A.east) edge[bend left, "S"]   (B.west)
            (B.west) edge[bend left, "U"]   (A.east)
            (B.east) edge["E"]              (C.west)
            (C.east) edge["S"]              (D.west);
\draw       ([yshift= 2pt] B.west) arc (235:-55:0.7) node[midway,below] {P};
\draw       ([yshift=-2pt] B.west) arc (-235:55:0.7) node[midway,above] {C};
\draw       (C.west) arc (235:-55:0.7) node[midway,below] {N};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In determination of `arc` radius and `end angle` the following relations were considered:

[image]

`arc` with `P` and `C` are vertical shifted accordingly for 2pt that they not overlap with bend lines between node 1 and 2.

Comment: @ZarkoAnother clever solution

Comment: @ Zarko How to put the value 0.8 rather than the letter S for example ?

Comment: @Fabrice, instead (in selected branch) `"S"` write `"0.8"` ...

Comment: @ Zarko With `0.8`, it works but with `0,8`, it does not work

Comment: problem is comma :) it means, that you have new option in quotes, so it is necessary to isolate it, i.e put 0,8 in curly braces: `"{0,8}"`.

Comment: @ Zarko Thank you very much for your explanation